# How to display a random quote as soon as page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, onload, quote

I am working on a random quote app. Quote is display when click a new quote button but I want quote already display when page loads. I invoked a function but it still does not work. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomQuote() {
    $('#get-quote').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Using jQuery
      $.ajax( {
          url: "http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(json) {
             // do something with data
             console.log(json);
             data = json[0];
             $('#quotation').html('"'+json.quote+'"');
             $('#author').html('-- '+json.author+' --');
             $('a.twitter-share-button').attr('data-text',json.quote);
           },

      });

    });
    $('#share-quote').on('click', function() {
         var tweetQuote=$('#quotation').html();
         var tweetAuthor=$('#author').html();
         var url='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(tweetQuote+"\n"+tweetAuthor);
         window.open(url)
    });

  }
  randomQuote();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Because you are still listening to the `onClick` event.

Comment: I changed to `click` event for both functions but it still does not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing click listener. inside randomeQuote() remove click listener.

keep your click listener out side of `document.ready`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       randomQuote(); // call initially and get random quote
});


function randomQuote() {
   
      $.ajax( {
          url: "https://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(json) {
             // do something with data
            
             data = json[0];
             $('#quotation').html('"'+json.quote+'"');
             $('#author').html('-- '+json.author+' --');
             $('a.twitter-share-button').attr('data-text',json.quote);
           },

      });

    $('#share-quote').on('click', function() {
         var tweetQuote=$('#quotation').html();
         var tweetAuthor=$('#author').html();
         var url='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(tweetQuote+"\n"+tweetAuthor);
         window.open(url)
    });

  }
  
 $('#get-quote').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      randomQuote();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="get-quote">get quote</button>

<div id="quotation"></div>
```

Comment: You can also remove the button in the html if you do not have a on click handler to get a new randomquote

Comment: It works now. I removed `onclick` and `e.preventDefault();`. I added `$('#get-quote').click(function() {
      randomQuote();
    });`

Comment: @KrittiyaClark Please accept the answer if this answer solved your problem. thanks

Comment: I am new here. Please guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onClick listeners so that when you call the function it will update directly.

```
function randomQuote() {
   $.ajax( {
      ...
      success: function(json) {
         ... //do updates
       },

  });
}
```

Comment: I still need a button to be clicked to display a next quote. Another solutions?

Comment: @KrittiyaClark: If you want it to always generate a qoute then call the function inside a `setInterval()`